# Solve the following trigonometric equation using product cancellation

Tags: trigonometry

Say I want to solve this equation using product cancellation:

$$\cos(2x+\frac {\pi}{2})\tan 3x = 0$$

The solutions are

$$\cos(2x+\frac {\pi}{2}) = 0 \space \vee \tan 3x = 0$$

Therefore

$$\cos(2x+\frac {\pi}{2}) = 0 \space \rightarrow 2x + \frac {\pi}{2} = \frac {\pi}{2} + k\pi \rightarrow x = \frac {\pi}{2} k$$

and

$$\tan3x = 0 \rightarrow 3x = k\pi \rightarrow x = \frac {\pi}{3}k$$

The solutions should be

$$x = \frac {\pi}{2}k \vee x=\frac{\pi}{3}k$$

The solution suggested by my book is this one

$$x = \frac {\pi}{3}k$$

Why is my solution different? Any hints?

Comment: $$\tan\dfrac\pi2=?$$

Comment: That is math error

Comment: Try to think about what it means (perhaps look at a graph of $\tan(x)$ and see what happens at $x=\pi/2$ - what would this mean for the product? Let me know if you want me to elaborate, but try for yourself first.

Comment: Thanks @Lovsovs I don't think I understand. At $x = \pi/2$ I think the product is equal to 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that while $$\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}} \left[ \cos\left( 2x+\frac{\pi}{2} \right) \right]=0$$
is true, $$\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}} \left[ \tan\left(3x\right) \right]=\infty$$
so we cannot not just say that the product is equal to zero. We can take the limit of the product,

$$\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}} \left[ \cos\left( 2x+\frac{\pi}{2} \right) \tan \left(3x\right)\right]=-\frac{2}{3}\not=0$$

Thus only $\frac{\pi}{3}k$ works.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I still haven't learned what $\lim$ means :/ +1 for your effort though.

Comment: @Cesare It just means "limit"; the limit of some expression as $x$ goes towards something (for instance zero or infinity) is just what the expression is approaching as $x$ does this. So in our case, $\tan(3x)$ grows towards infinity as $x$ approaches $\pi/2$. What this means for your problem is that when you multiply the two functions, you can't say that the product is just zero because of the $\cos$, since the $\tan$ becomes infinitely big - and which of the two tendencies (0 or infinity) dominates the other is determined by taking the limit. Here it was kind of a tie; 2/3, but still not 0.

Comment: @Cesare Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}}[cos(2x+\frac{\pi}{2})tan(3x)]=-\frac{2}{3}$$

Comment: Could you explain how this answer is related to the question?

Comment: $$-\frac{2}{3}\neq0$$